# Bootlooping BSoD SYSTEM_LICENSE_VIOLATION to Automatic Recovery

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod

##### Here's what the computer did when I booted back up (in simple terms):

1. BSoD SYSTEM_LICENSE_VIOLATION, restart
2. Automatic Recovery, fails to fix, restart
3. Repeat about twice
4. Boots to the Automatic Recovery Options, choose an option, fails, restart
5. BSoD
6. Repeat from number 4 on this list

Now it just starts at number 4 every time someone boots it up.

When I last used my computer, it gave a notification saying that there were drive errors.
This was when I was watching a screen-recording I did myself, [so I wasn't doing anything that touched the system files, or the RAM.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/system-license-violation-bsod/0bfa2a04-56af-4e73-bff9-ce80f9e78a0c)

Anybody got an idea why my computer did this?
(I could reset or reinstall windows, but I would like to avoid the extra work that brings)

Thanks in advance.

Forgot to add I have two usbs with PEs on them, one a windows installer, the other, [HBCD PE.](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/)

##### PC SPECS:

- Dell Vostro 270s
- Intel i5
- 8GB of RAM
- NVIDIA Geforce 620 (Old I know)
- 250GB Samsung SSD

My computer is about 6 years old -_-

But the SSD was a upgrade from about 2 years ago, so I don't think it's the problem. (and I'm hoping it's not the problem)

##### EDIT 1:

- Safe Mode: Unbootable
- SMART Data of C Drive: Healthy
- RAM Check in BIOS: 8GB (So nothing isn't being found)

Comment: We need an image of the BSOD message. Your disk seemed to have had a catastrophic error. Use one of your boot USBs to check the SMART data of the disk. See "4.5.3. Diagnostic - Diagnose a hard drive" in [Presentation of Hiren Boot CD PE features](https://us.informatiweb.net/tutorials/it/live-cd/hiren-boot-cd-pe-presentation-of-the-live-cd-features--2.html). Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774518/edit) any additional data into your post.

Comment: I'm hoping it's **not** a RAM problem, as I wouldn't like to be spending money on RAM

Comment: @harrymc Should I get the 'C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP' file, and what about a memory test, as well as the SMART data?

Comment: Let's start with the SMART data - the disk seems like the prime suspect.

Comment: @harrymc have added the smart data, the ram situation, and is safe mode bootable. I think at this point I should reset . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardware seems to be in good shape, so there is no explanation
for this catastrophic crash. Perhaps, if the computer was not protected
against power outage, that a particular power failure happened at
exactly the wrong moment.

I agree that resetting the computer is the only action left to do.

Be careful in the future to always have backups for your data,
and perhaps better protect your computer against power problems,
in case such a problem arrives again (if it does, a more careful
examination of the hardware will be in order).

Comment: I **do** have a back up, as I store my documents, pictures, and videos on a external drive.

Comment: For anybody interested, this answer didn't answer my question as my computer started not getting to the BSoD at all, but it started just saying `Windows didn't start correctly`. In the end, I had to reinstall windows. But thanks to @harrymc for helping me get here and test my hardware, for that reason I'm still accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes, not every catastrophic error can be recovered and Windows reinstallation is sometimes the fastest solution.